# 404 error while attaching css file though file path is correct.

Tags: css, wordpress

my css file exists in my localhost as follow :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\eghotok\jquery_ui\test.css
```

I wrote code to add css file as follows:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/query_ui/test.css">
```

But I got 404 error for this file. 
Even I checked this error by developer tool. it says :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/eghotok/query_ui/test.css`

I checked again and again the physical location of css file and location in my code. What am I doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link-tag the "j" on "jquery" is missing:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/eghotok/query_ui/test.css
```